# what is total and the first number in "ls -l" cmd shell?

Tags: shell, directory

```
total XX
drwx--xr-x  2 login  wheel  XX May  25 10:10 test0
-rwx--xr--  1 login  wheel   4 May  25 10:11 test1
dr-x---r--  2 login  wheel  XX May  25 10:12 test2
-r-----r--  2 login  wheel   1 May  25 10:13 test3
```

is the output of ls -l.

What is "2" in the first line and "total XX" ? googling did not help

Comment: What system are you using? What implementation of `ls` are you using? Do you really see `XX` in the output as text?

Comment: @KamilCuk i m using linux, but not sure exactly waht, it's a coding bootcamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manual says:

> `-l`      (The lowercase letter ``ell''.)  List in long format.  (See below.)  A total sum for all the file sizes
>                is output on a line before the long listing.

and below... (emphasis' mine)

> If the `-l` option is given, the following information is displayed for
>   each file: file mode, **number of links**,
>        owner name, group name, **number of bytes in the file**, abbreviated month, day-of-month file was last modified,
>        hour file last modified, minute file last modified, and the pathname.

Comment: what is XX? total XX - means the dir count of files is hidden?

Comment: a directory is a kind of *file* (very special).

Comment: but what is total XX?

Comment: as said in the answer : *A total sum for all the file sizes is output on a line before the long listing.*

Comment: sorry but what is XX if it's not a number? it's not 20 in roman numbers lol... it shows "total XX" cuz some files have file size in bytes as "XX" - what is XX for a single file size?

Comment: You mean it is really "XX"??? Probably because the file size for a directory is not available. That is the case for some filesystems. Which one is yours?

Comment: baptitste yenes - i mean my file system is unix. dont know exactly which one

Answer (score 1):

Puff, from [posix ls](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ls.html):

> If the -l option is specified without -L, the following information shall be written:
>
> ```
> "%s %u %s %s %u %s %s\n", <file mode>, <number of links>,
> <owner name>, <group name>, <number of bytes in the file>,
> <date and time>, <pathname>
> ```

So the second column is `<number of links>`.

The fifth column is `<number of bytes in the file>`.